# Is there an equivelant of javascript template literals in archetype?

Tags: smart-contracts

Is it possible to include the value of variables in error messages?

For example I would like to do something like this Javascript / Archetype hybrid:

```
do_require(feeOne + feeTwo = feeTotal, `Fees do not correctly add up! Fee one: ${feeOne} + fee two: ${feeTwo} does not equal the fee total of: ${feeTotal}`);
```

Through some trial and error I found that it IS possible to do this:
`do_require(feeOne + feeTwo = feeTotal, feeOne);`
This prints out something like:

```
     Error: the object {
  "value": "5000000"
} was thrown, throw an Error :)
```

This has been useful for debugging, but even this would require me to run the test three times if I want to look at each of the 3 variables in the line above, so I would like to know if there is a better way.

I've tried search for template literal in the archetype docs and searching tezos stack exchange/ google but I may well be using the wrong search term here as I only know what it is called in JS.

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for late reply.
Short answer is no, not as you describe it, but it is possible to embed any value in an fail value thanks to tuple.

```
fail(("A MESSAGE", feeOne, feeTwo, feeTotal));
```